# Loop an Array with in array

Tags: php

I really need some help.

I have a sql query that selects the correct table, column.

However, I would like to loop the content of the data but when I do I get the following result:

```
["",""]
["Pretoria"]
["",""]
wc
["Pretoria","Cape Town","Garden Route"]
[""]
[""]
```

How do I only get the items within the [""]?

```
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $catetogry = $_GET['category'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM #__jsn_users");
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();


    foreach($results as $obj) {

        $value = $obj->suburbs_i_cover;

        if(!empty($value)){
            echo $value;
            echo"<br>";
        }
    }
}


Output: var_dump($obj->suburbs_i_cover);
NULL NULL string(0) "" string(7) "["",""]" ["",""]
string(12) "["Pretoria"]" ["Pretoria"]
string(0) "" string(7) "["",""]" ["",""]
string(0) "" string(2) "wc" wc
string(0) "" string(39) "["Pretoria","Cape Town","Garden Route"]" 
["Pretoria","Cape Town","Garden Route"]
string(4) "[""]" [""]
string(4) "[""]" [""]
string(0) "" string(27) "["Pretoria","Johannesburg"]" 
["Pretoria","Johannesburg"]
string(34) "["Hartbeespoort Dam","Klerksdorp"]" ["Hartbeespoort 
Dam","Klerksdorp"]
string(47) "["Port Elizabeth","Jeffreys Bay","East London"]" ["Port 
Elizabeth","Jeffreys Bay","East London"]
string(47) "["Port Elizabeth","Jeffreys Bay","East London"]" ["Port 
Elizabeth","Jeffreys Bay","East London"]
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `var_dump($obj->suburbs_i_cover);` instead of `echo $value;` to your question, please?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus added :)

Comment: So you want to loop `["Pretoria","Cape Town","Garden Route"]` as if it was an array?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, please.

Comment: You aren't chaining the $query object in accordance with syntax from the documentation -- you are actually overwriting the `$query` variable.  The way you are using a raw $query string, I don't think you need getQuery() at all.  Please reread the Joomla manual for appropriate syntax.  I don't think you are meant to use `$_GET` like that in Joomla either.  If you are using `$catetogry` or `$name` in your query, I hope you are quoting/escaping as prescribed by the Joomla Documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of where the `["Pretoria","Cape Town","Garden Route"]` string comes from but it seems like a good candidate to be decoded with [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
foreach($results as $obj) {

    // Try to treat each suburbs_i_cover as a JSON string
    // and decode it to a native PHP array
    $value = json_decode($obj->suburbs_i_cover);

    // If we have an array then we can loop it
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $sub_value) {
            echo 'sub_value: '.$sub_value.'<br>';
        }
    }
    else {
        // The json_decode() did not result in an array so show the original value
        echo 'not array: '.$obj->suburbs_i_cover.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your getting another array? try to do foreach again inside

```
foreach($results as $obj) {

 $value = $obj->suburbs_i_cover;

    if(!empty($value)){
        foreach($value as $x) {  
         echo $x;
         echo"<br>";
        }
    }
}
```